# I am getting error that say -> TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, session-cookies, connect-mongo

`**Error TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'**

** MY code is:**

````
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/pizza';

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', function () {
        console.log('Database connected');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    //  session 
    let mongoStore = new MongoDbStore({
    mongooseConnection: connection,
    collection: 'sessions'
})```


```// session config

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    store: mongoStore,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 } // 24 hour
}))```
`
**This is the error i am getting **`
````

const MongoDbStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
^

TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'
at Object. (C:\Projects\pizza\server.js:21:46)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

```
`Please help to solving the error `




 `**I tried some solution  from thee stackOverflow but still not able to solve the problem**`
```

Comment: Cover all error